# Matplotlib twinx for different scales

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I am using matplotlib twinx for graphing multiple variables on the same axes. But I have a problem, for which I can't find a solution. For simplicity, I have attached little code and graph plotted by that code below.
In this picture, I need those bars to be displayed at the bottom of axes as shown in picture 2. But in picture 2, yticks of ax1t remained as the same. I also need them to be displayed at the bottom. How can I do that?

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot([4, 2, 8, 6, 4, 7, 3, 5])
ax1t = ax1.twinx()
ax1t.bar(np.arange(8), [45, 42, 55, 36, 58, 45, 48, 62], alpha=0.4)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Picture 2
[image]

Comment: You would like to add label value for each bar?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by *"bars to be displayed at the bottom of axes along with their y tick labels"*. Please spend some more thoughts on describing the problem. What do you get and in how far it does not meet your expectation. [Edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Ok, I'm editing..

Comment: _This added to the confusion!_ I don't know about the others. The bars are already at the bottom.

Comment: Do you mean you want to increase the y axis scale of bar chart?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess this is what you want -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.plot([4, 2, 8, 6, 4, 7, 3, 5])
ax1t = ax1.twinx()

ax1t.bar(np.arange(8), [45, 42, 55, 36, 58, 45, 48, 62], alpha=0.4)
ax1t.set_ylim([10,500])
ax1t.set_yticks([10, 50, 90])
plt.show()
```

Change the y axis scale using `set_ylim` and then explicitly pass the y ticks using `set_yticks`. You play around with the parameters to adjust it according to your convenience.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[from matplotlib examples](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/subplots_demo.html)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, sharex=True, sharey=True)
ax1.plot([4, 2, 8, 6, 4, 7, 3, 5])
ax2.bar(np.arange(8), [45, 42, 55, 36, 58, 45, 48, 62], alpha=0.4)

# Fine-tune figure; make subplots close to each other and hide x ticks for
# all but bottom plot.
f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)
plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in f.axes[:-1]], visible=False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You created another subplot to do that. But, I need to plot them in the same axes.

Comment: If you want them on the same axis, then the only way to push the bars down is to modify the y-axis scale. Why can't you put them on different subplots?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Plotly library, which could easily do that with great visualisation.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

trace1 = go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[1.5, 1, 1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9]
)
trace2 = go.Bar(
    x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[1, 0.5, 0.7, -1.2, 0.3, 0.4]
)

data = [trace1, trace2]
py.iplot(data, filename='bar-line')
```

Result (it is .png format, therefore not interactive)
[image]